# Android app with basic configuration not running on android version 6.0

Tags: android

today when I created a sample app "My Application" with all basic configuration like

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.development.av.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

with just one activity displaying hello world text.

even, my manifest file don't have any permission.

when I run this app on my testing device. its running well. which is having android version... 5.1.1

Then I send this app to my another android device which is having android version 6.0
but this device is not opening this app.
installation was successful.
but when I open this app, it gives me error saying,
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6LaJ.jpg)

when I click on try to resolve it gives another screen with option clear data ...after clicking on it it gives me another screen "app info" screen as...

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVj8m.jpg)

but I didn't understand what is the problem with my app?
anyone please suggest...

my updated build configuration is as follows

```
compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.development.av.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

but no luck !!!!

Here is my full source code of my app

**build.gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.development.av.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.development.av.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.development.av.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.development.av.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: can you at least post your logcat error ?

Comment: I am not getting any error in android studio. when I build apk fie of this project and send to the android 6.0 it was saying app stop working. it is working properly in my another device of android 5.1.1

Comment: Yes. Read the logs! That popup means nothing

Answer (score 0):

You need `compileSdk 23` if you actually want to run on API 23 and earlier

And since you are  using build tools 26, you might as well compile with 26

Comment: I upgrade my compile sdk version to 26 bt no luck...you can see my edited question. I have posted my new build configuration

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the logcat, then

Answer (score 0):

## Target SDK Version Issue

**To make your App run on Android 6 use:**

```
targetSdkVersion 23 and compileSdkVersion 23
```

*instead of*

```
targetSdkVersion 22 and compileSdkVersion 22
```

> It's Recommended to Use the code below to Support all Devices till Android Oreo

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.development.av.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Comment: I upgrade my compile sdk version to 26 , now my build configuration is same as above but no luck.. my app not working on android 6.0

Comment: you can see my question ..I have posted my updated build configuration

Comment: Can you share your complete Source Code; so that I can review the issue and try to help you better.

Comment: please check my updated question. I have posted full source code.

Comment: hey, i notice something.. yesterday I was using my android 5.1.1 device for testing my project... so my project was working fine on that.. then I share that app using shareit to android 6.0 device. then it was showing error app stopped working. today I used my android 6.0 device for testing using usb debugging. and it is running my app successfully. then again I tried yesterdays procedure. but again my app not working on 6.0.... means when I use usb debugging its working. but when I share it from 5.1.1 device to 6.0 device its not working on 6.0.... why its happening???